# htaccess Mod Rewrite $_GET to normal URL

Tags: .htaccess

I have this Rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /home.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [L,QSA]
```

which currently rewrites things like home.php?id=blog&slug=123 to be /blog/123

how can i change it so the `123` is text and numbers rather than just numbers?

I have this in my htaccess file that is redirecting:

```
home.php?id=services to /services
```

i want to also be able to do:

```
home.php?id=blog&slug=slug-goes-here to be /blog/slug-goes-here
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the URLs that you want to redirect.

Comment: Do you have only above rule in your .htaccess OR there is some other code too? Better you post your current .htaccess in the question.

Comment: You need to add the hyphen to the class of accepted characters. See my edited answer for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `[0-9]+` part with `[\w-]+`. This will match the character 0-9, a-z, A-Z, _ (the underscore) and - (the hyphen):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /home.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Also, you might want to read something about the basics of regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: i seem to be getting 404 Not Found ?

Comment: @charliejsford What does your server log say?